# Can not open webpage using UIWebView

Tags: ios

I'm writing an app which lets users open up youtube exercise/fitness videos from a table view. So, I want to pass in a given website address for each cell in the table view. The code executes without errors but in the simulator does not open any webpage when I select a cell. Here is the code of the implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Create a URL object
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//Switch values based on exerciseNumber
switch (exerciseNumber) {
    case 0:{
        self.title = @"Straight Leg Raise";
        urlAddress = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sb_2OVC4TuM";
    }
        break;
    case 1:{
        self.title = @"Supine Hip Abduction with Elastic Band";
        urlAddress = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gnmbjrjEuM";
        break;
    }
    default:{
        self.title = @"No Exercise Selected";
        urlAddress = @"http://www.rehabview.com";
        break;
    }
}

//Create a URL request object
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//load the request in the UIWebView
[webView loadRequest:request];  

}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is happening on the real device?

Comment: Just a blank view when I click on the top two cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your `NSURL` object after your switch statement that sets the `urlAddress` string.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I thought I had tried that but evidently not.